# svelte and swiper pagination problems

Tags: svelte, swiper.js

I have the basic functionality of Swiper in my website but the problem is that I am trying to get the drag pagination of my slider to continue the same functionality as clicking the "pagination bullets". Whenever I use the drag functionality of the swiper it doesn't register within the pagination bullets.

**Live Website**

[View Website with Sliders](https://brendonavalos-v4.vercel.app/)

**Some Images**

[Broken Slideshow Triggered from Dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBavt.jpg)
[Correct pagination functionality from clicking the navigation buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Z24.jpg)

I used swiper methods like "swiper.loopDestroy()" to solve the problem but now i get an error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: swiper.loopDestroy is not a function"

I have a feeling it has something to do with scoping or 'onMount" acting as a for loop.

```
<script>
    import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';
    import 'swiper/css/bundle';

    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(() => {
        const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            // Optional parameters
            autoHeight: true,
            spaceBetween: 300,
            simulateTouch: true,
            observeParents: true,
            observer: true,
            // If we need pagination

            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true
            }
        });
        swiper.loopDestroy()
    });
</script>
```

Is this a scoping problem or is it an swiper import problem?

I am trying to be able to use swiper's methods but they don't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Is the base functionality there if you remove the `detachEvents` call?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question to be more specific with some links to the actual project. The main functionality is there it just breaks when you use the touch feature.

Comment: I can use the methods just fine. First of all I would recommend **not** using global selectors, it's a bad idea. You can pass DOM instances directly, so either use `bind:this={...}`  on an element, or better yet, use an action, then you do not even need `onMount`. ([example](https://svelte.dev/repl/4c3a24dcdf774c4b963a61e043ba67e2?version=3.55.1))

Comment: This worked <3 Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you attach to the correct elements by using `bind:this={}` or an action instead of global selectors, e.g.

```
<script>
    //..

    function initSwiper(node) {
        var swiper = new Swiper(node, {
            navigation: {
                // Use relative selectors here
                nextEl: node.querySelector(".swiper-button-next"),
                prevEl: node.querySelector(".swiper-button-prev"),
            },
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="swiper" use:initSwiper>
...
```

Actions also take care of the timing issue, so you do not need `onMount` to wait for the element to be created.